# Meaning of a comparator statement in C++

Tags: c++, if-statement, comparator

I am reading this code in C++ 
http://ajmarin.alwaysdata.net/codes/problems/952/ and I don't understand what this `&=` in the code does:

```
int k = 5;
int ts = 5;
bool possible = true;
```

And it have this line:

```
if(!(possible &= k == ts)) 
    break;
```

I want to know what is the meaning of `"&="` I am new in C++ language and I've never seen something like this for example in java, or at least I don't know the meaning.

The right hand of the statement returns `"1"` due to the fact that ( `k == ts` ) that is ( `5 == 5`) but the left hand ( `possible &= k` ) don't know the meaning..

Thank you

Comment: You should slap whoever wrote that code.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth May be he isn't allowed to slap his teacher ;) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

&= is [Bitwise AND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0zec0b2.aspx) assigning the result to the lhs( a&=b  =>  a=a&b). (like +=)

It will perform a logical AND and assign the result to possible.

---

Due to [Operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) the expression will be like: `possible &= (k == ts)`.

Which means that it will evaulate `(k == ts)` resulting in a boolean, make a logical and with `possible`, store it in `possible`  and return it as a result.

Answer (score 5):

It's equivalent to:

```
possible &= (k == ts);
if (! possible)
```

and is further equivalent to

```
possible = possible & (k == ts);
if (! possible)
```

Here, `&` is the bitwise AND. `num & 0` will always gives you `0` while `num & 1` will give you `1` if the least significant bit of `num` is `1` or `0` otherwise.

To read on, check out

- [Bitwise AND Assignment Operator (`&=`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/k6d7hcca%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [C++ Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Answer (score 2):

It is a bitwise-AND-assignment, which is a [Compound Assignment Operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++). It is equivalent to the following statement:

```
possible = possible & (k == ts);
if(!possible)
    ....
```

Note that your original code-style is considered by many to be an anti-pattern, and you should in general avoid assignments in `if` statements (e.g. [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/162256/in-c-and-c-what-methods-can-prevent-accidental-use-of-the-assignment-where) and [here](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/cplusplus/EXP19-CPP.+Do+not+perform+assignments+in+conditional+expressions)).